# Finding the Min & Max Times for Multiple Individuals

Tags: datetime, max, excel-2010, pivot-table, min

For work I have a report where I compile the number of calls, emails, and texts a person makes each day.  Along with this I need to pick out the earliest (Min) and the latest (max) times for each of those actions.  I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way to me to pull this data from the date column rather than scrolling down for each person and finding the information.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is definitely an easier way. What we need to rely on is that Excel stores times as the number of days since 0th January 1900 (so 1st January 1900 is day 1). Therefore, finding the earliest and latest times is simple a matter of finding the min and max values within a specific day.

I'm assuming that your data is set out as in the following. If it isn't, you can just edit my formula as appropriate.

```
A  B         C        D
1  Person    Date     Time
2  Steve     Monday   14:00
3  Steve     Monday   14:05
4  Sharon    Monday   12:00
5  Steve     Tuesday  09:00
6  Sharon    Tuesday  15:00
```

What we need to do is find the minimum time for Steve, *given* that `date = Monday`. We need to use an array formula. Array formulas let us 'look up' against more than one cell at the same time. The formula I would use is:

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A6="Steve",IF(B2:B6="Monday",C2:C6)))
```

Instead of clicking 'Enter' when you use this formula, you need to click Ctrl+Shift+Enter i.e., you enter the formula above and click Ctrl+Shift+Enter and Excel will return:

```
={MIN(IF(A2:A6="Steve",IF(B2:B6="Monday",C2:C6)))}
```

Can you see how to add more constraints to the look up? I've included an example screenshot below, where I've made a bigger table and also made the 'Steve' and 'Monday' references refer out to a cell, rather than just being hardcoded into the formula.

[image: excel example]